# Need a regular expression to check if pattern match

Tags: sql, regex, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need a regular expression which will check if the first 2 characters are 0x and next 4 characters will be Alphanumeric characters

```
Example:  0x13H3
```

It should exceed more that 6 characters.

This seems to be not working `REGEXP_LIKE(string, '[0x]A-Z0-9')`

Can anyone please guide me ?

Comment: You misplaced the square brackets, `0x[A-Z0-9]+` / `0x[A-Z0-9]{4}` / `0x[A-Fa-f0-9]{4}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `REGEXP_LIKE(string, '0x[A-Z0-9]{4}')`

`[]` is a character class, which states that only the chars or range described inside it can be matched. So your regex pattern: `[0x]A-Z0-9`, says to match either 0 or x, litterally followed by `A-Z0-9`, so it would have matched either '0A-Z0-9' or 'xA-Z0-9'.

Explanation:

```
0x[A-Z0-9]{4}

0x          matches 0x
[A-Z0-9]{4} matches uppercase and numbers four times
```